# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.setDurability in hive shell

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am a newbie to `hadoop`, `hbase` and `hive` environment. I configured with the hadoop and hbase node with fully distributed mode. I have inserted some sample data in hive table.

I have created one table hive for hbase table for access the hbase table data thorugh hive and read the data from hive table also vice versa like

```
create external table testing 
(key string
, name string
, age int
, year int
, salary int) 
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
(hbase.columns.mapping = :key,cf1:name,cf1:id,cf2:year,cf2:salary)
TBLPROPERTIES (hbase.table.name = basetbalename)
```

and the hbase table i created two column family .

```
create 'hbasetablename' ,'cf1', 'cf2'
```

Everything is working fine.But while am overwriting the data from hive to hbase table getting the error. I dont know why the error is coming.

Am trying to overwrite the data like this

```
hbase> insert overwrite table sample select concat(name, ':', age) as key,name,age,year,salary from empdetail;'
```

While am overwrite the table getting the following error.

> Query ID = master_20150411092222_f7cf8d94-8449-48f3-8aff-06ef8213f776
>       Total jobs = 1
>       Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
>       Starting Job = job_1428713373268_0001, 
>       Tracking URL = http://master:8088/proxy/application_1428713373268_0001/
>       Kill Command = /home/master/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1428713373268_0001
>       Hadoop job information for Stage-0: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0 2015-04-11 09:23:40,198 Stage-0 map = 0%,
>       reduce = 0% 2015-04-11 09:24:07,628 Stage-0 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU3.25 sec 2015-04-11 09:24:08,674 Stage-0 map =
>   0%,reduce = 0%
>       2015-04-11 09:24:41,742 Stage-0 map = 100%,  reduce = 0% MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 3 seconds 250 msec Ended 
>       Job = job_1428713373268_0001 with errors Error during job, obtaining debugging information..
>       Job Tracking URL: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1428713373268_0001/ Examining
>   task ID: task_1428713373268_0001_m_000000 (and more)rom job
>   job_1428713373268_0001
>       Task with the most failures(4):Task ID:task_1428713373268_0001_m_000000
>   URL:http://master:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1428713373268_0001&tipid=task_1428713373268_0001_m_000000
>       Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
>       Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.setDurability(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Durability;)V
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:179)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163) atjava.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.setDurability(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Durability;)V
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat$MyRecordWriter.write(HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat.java:142)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat$MyRecordWriter.write(HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat.java:117)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HivePassThroughRecordWriter.write(HivePassThroughRecordWriter.java:40)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:714)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:95)atorg.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:493)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:170) 
>       .. 8 more
>       FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
>       MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
>       Stage-Stage-0: Map: 1 Cumulative CPU: 3.25 sec   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
>       Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 3 seconds 250 msec

I dont know how to resolve this bug.In hive i set classpath some jar files as

```
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.0.0.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/hbase-client-1.0.0.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/hbase-common-1.0.0.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/hbase-protocol-1.0.0.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/hbase-server-1.0.0.jar;
    add jar ${env:HIVE_HOME}/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar;
```

After i set the value in `hive-site.xml` file also the hive aux jar class path but is not working.

I set the dynamic partition also in hive shell.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true 
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

But it's not working. If i did any alignment and spelling mistake please apologize for that.I don't know where the mistake .Please help me .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please any one help me .Alignment suggestion is not important now.

Comment: Do you want sql querying on HBase data? If yes, then i would recommend Phoenix(http://phoenix.apache.org/). It works far better with HBase.

Comment: HI Anil Gupta. Thanks for the comments.Right now i have configured the hive and hbase.Is there any possible for this error in hive.I will check the phoenix.But i need to work with hive only. Can you please help me to resolve the hive bug.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe that you will have to upgrade Hadoop's version.

It appears that Hive is trying to access the unset method of the org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put class.